# DataTables inform load time while loading AJAX data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have some tables that start empty and DataTables requests WebServer for the data.

It's ok to take some minutes to load it. DataTables shows default Loading message. But I'd like to add a counter informing how long the loading is running, instead of a simple Loading text or some wacky animation.

I can't find a way to do it on its documentation. Is it possible?

Update: MonkeyZeus's answer worked perfectly. Here's my final code:

```
// ...
,dataTablesLoading: function(e, settings, processing ){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var targetJs = e.target;
        var target = $(targetJs);
        var timerContainer = target.find('.dataTables_empty');
//tlog(targetJs,'targetJs');
//tlog(target,'target');
//tlog(timerContainer,'timerContainer');

        if(processing){
                var timer = 0;
                var timerHandler = setInterval(function(){
                    timer++;
                    var hours = Math.floor(timer/3600);
                    var minutes = Math.floor((timer-(hours*60))/60);
                    var secs = timer-(hours*3600)-(minutes*60);

                    var timerText = hours+':'+minutes.lpad("0",2)+':'+secs.lpad("0",2);
tlog(timerText,'timerText');
//tlog(timerContainer,'timerContainer');
                    timerContainer.text("Loading... "+timerText);
                },1000);


            targetJs.setAttribute("data-loading-timer",timerHandler);
tlog(timerHandler,'timerHandler processing');
        }else{
            var timerHandler = parseInt(targetJs.getAttribute("data-loading-timer"));
tlog(timerHandler,'timerHandler not processing');

            if(timerHandler>0)
                clearInterval(timerHandler);
        }

    },1000);
}
// ...
$('#...')
    .on( 'processing.dt', Framework.utils.dataTablesLoading )
    .DataTable({...})
```

Comment: You will never be able to do that ( I guess you think of a kind of progressbar) unless you have a connection to the server  aside which can return back status, number of rows etc.  But a clock showing the elapsed time would be easy.

Comment: Tnx for reply. No need for progressbar ou % completed. I just want an hour-minute-second counter to be able to know how long loading has been running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[First, you will need to enable `processing` when invoking the datatable:](https://datatables.net/reference/option/processing)

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "processing": true
} );
```

[Next, you will need to declare what happens instead of the default Loading message using the `dt` namespace's `processing` event listener:](https://datatables.net/reference/event/processing)

```
// This event will fire twice so pay attention to the processing parameter
$('#example').on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
    if( processing  === true ) {
        alert('Hey, we are processing!');
        // some custom code which targets #processingIndicator and applies some timer plug-in or whatever; you figure it out.
    }
    else {
        alert('Hey, we are done processing!');
        // some custom code which targets #processingIndicator and hides it; you figure it out.
    }
} )
.dataTable();
```

---

Additionally, long load times have a UX aspect to consider as well so definitely check out https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/80858/45170 if you want to make a nicer experience.

Comment: Thanks gonna try it. I have a cache feature, once data is loaded it's stored in a file and that file is used instead of querying the DB. The cache lasts 1h, but then it needs to be updated because I can't let data to be too outdated.

Comment: @Hikari I see. If you have the ability to create cron jobs/scheduled tasks then you could opt to set up an hourly refresh of the cache file instead of placing the burden on your users.

Comment: @Hikari any luck with this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried it and the even triggered, once when the loading starts and once when loading finishes. But I couldn't figure from inside the event if it's starting or finishing. Do you know the best practice for that?

Comment: I could give you the answer but that's no fun, try reading the documentation which I linked; specifically  `function ( e, settings, processing )`.

Comment: @Hikari no worries. It sounds like you might have figured it out so I will update my answer :)

Comment: And yes I could make a Java app that would load DB and save a .json file where PHP would point. But that would add 1 more infrastructure element to handle. The monitoring website will be used by very few ppl, so I'll just keep these infos inside PHP webapp with 1h cache.